# Is there any way to get credits outside of stash boxes?

Tags: lawbreakers

Opening stash boxes randomly generates four items in the form of various cosmetic icons and skins for characters and weapons (and even the bottoms of their footwear). Sometimes, you can also receive some credits instead of a skin. You also receive credits if you open a box and get a duplicate of something you already have. Collecting enough of these credits allows you to simply purchase the skin you want rather than waiting to receive it from a loot box by chance.

So far, I've only received credits from receiving duplicate skins or just getting credits from a stash box, but are there any other ways to get credits outside of these two ways?

Answer (score 1):

(I can only confirm this as a feature in PC right now)

There is at least a third way to get credits (on PC).

In the main menu, there is a tab labelled "Tutorials".  It also shows a credit symbol beside that.

For every tutorial you watch, you recieve credits (the first time).  You don't get a lot from the tutorials, I believe it is around 50-60 credits total (I'm having trouble finding the numbers online).

Also worth noting that you only have to [watch the first 10 seconds](https://www.reddit.com/r/lawbreakers/comments/6sb963/psa_you_only_need_to_watch_the_first_ten_seconds/) to get the credit reward.

As far as I'm aware ([and could find online](https://www.reddit.com/r/lawbreakers/comments/6qcl34/how_to_get_credits/)) these are the only ways to get credits currently.

Comment: From my memory, it was 10cr for all Hero tutorials, and a few of the gamemode ones. You can also purchase credits, if you really want to.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf you're able to purchase credits on PC? On PS4, I've only seen the option to purchase Stash Boxes

Comment: Oh ahhh my bad, staches, not creds. My mistake!